# How to setup mdadm raid1 auto-assembly, where external bitmap is itself on another mdadm raid1?

Tags: systemd, lvm, mdadm, device-mapper

How can the assembling of a raid (as via information stored in `mdadm.conf`) succeed, given that its assembling requires a **bitmap** file, which itself is only available **after** another device has become available (another raid)?

**My questions background**

With [mdmam](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) it is possible to create a "write-indent-log" (a.k.a. bitmap), which is something that in the case of the "simple" raid level raid1, mostly helps to reduced resync time.

In two simple cases (`--bitmap=none` and `--bitmap=internal`) the raid device can easily be made available. However in the case of "external bitmap" (`--bitmap=/path/to/bitmap-file-on-a-ext2-3-4-fs`) the assembling can of course only succeed upon the moment, when this external bitmap file itself is available.

The problem I experience on my GNU/linux debian 10 (buster) machine, is that the bitmap file for the /dev/md/raid1_on_hdds raid1 assembly, is stored on a filesystem which resides on the /dev/md/raid1_on_ssds array.

My question, hence circles arround what configurations files `mdadm.conf`, `dmsetup`-related-config and `lvm`-related condig. As well as `systemd`-related-config, to all those software modules related to properly assemble the array.

**Update (some more info)**

this seem to be the available `systemd` unit files related to `md` device creation.

```
root@ada:/etc/systemd/system# find /usr/lib/systemd/system -name 'md*'
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.timer
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdadm-grow-continue@.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdmonitor-oneshot.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdmon@.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdadm-last-resort@.timer
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.timer
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdadm-shutdown.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdmonitor-oneshot.timer
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdadm.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdadm-waitidle.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdadm-last-resort@.service
```